# Why cant I create/update new entrie in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

Ive been trying all day to create a new entry in my table. Sorry for all the text in spanish. I hope it is not a problem.

[image]

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $nueva_tienda = $_POST['nueva_tienda'];
    if(!empty($nueva_tienda)){
        echo "not empty";
        include('connection.php');
        mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO tiendas (nombre) VALUES ('$nueva_tienda')");
    }
    else{
        echo "Porfavor llena todos los campos";
    }
}
else{
    echo "No form has been submitted";
}

?>



<h1>Nueva tienda</h1>
    <form action="processing2.php" method="post">
    <p>Nombre de la nueva tienda: <input type="text" name="nueva_tienda" maxlength="50"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
    </form>
```

EDIT:

Added connection include file from comments:

```
 <?php $hostname = "localhost"; 
       $username = "root"; 
       $password1 = ""; 
       $dbname = "inventario_collares"; //making the connection to mysql        
       $dbc = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password1, $dbname) OR die("could not connect to database, ERROR: ".mysqli_connect_error()); 
     //set encoding 
       mysqli_set_charset($dbc, "utf8"); 
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is "nombre" a number or string? What does your database look like?

Comment: Thanks for helping. No I'm not getting any errors just nothing happens. Nombre is a string it is the name of one column in my database. The database has just 2 columns the I'd and nombre.

Comment: is the data type of the column nombre a string type: varchar or text or char?

Comment: the data type is varchar

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of your connection class.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $nueva_tienda = $_POST['nueva_tienda'];
    if(!empty($nueva_tienda)){
        echo "not empty";
        include('connection.php');
    //create an object for your connection class
        $dbc=new connection();
        mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO tiendas (nombre) VALUES ('$nueva_tienda')");
    }else{
        echo "Porfavor llena todos los campos";
    }
    }else{
    echo "No form has been submitted";
}


?>



<h1>Nueva tienda</h1>
    <form action="processing2.php" method="post">
    <p>Nombre de la nueva tienda: <input type="text" name="nueva_tienda" maxlength="50"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
    </form>
```

Comment: that didnt solve it. I think that is not where the problem lies because i dont even get the "not empty" echo.

Comment: Echo the value of  '$nueva_tienda' after   $nueva_tienda = $_POST['nueva_tienda'];

Comment: both php scsript and html are in same processing2.php page??

Comment: originaly they werent. I tried to put them in the same one to see if it worked but it still didnt work

Comment: Refer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237683/insert-data-to-database-via-html-form-in-the-same-page

Comment: still nothing! What else might it be?

Comment: Can I see your connection class?

Comment: <?php


$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password1 = "";
$dbname = "inventario_collares";

//making the connection to mysql

$dbc = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password1, $dbname) OR die("could not connect to database, ERROR: ".mysqli_connect_error());

//set encoding

mysqli_set_charset($dbc, "utf8");

?>

Comment: sorry if it is difficult to understand. I cant upload an image and it deletes the spaces automatically when I post

Answer (score 0):

1) Turn on PHP error outputting at the **top** of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

2) set this line:

```
mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO tiendas (nombre) 
 VALUES ('$nueva_tienda')") 
    or die("Error MySQL Line ".__LINE__." :".mysqli_Error($dbc));
```

This will output any problems if the MySQL insert query fails.

If you do both of these things and still get no error, then the problem is elsewhere (such as is your file called `processing2.php`? etc.).